# Table Function UNNEST not working in DB2 10.1

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

I'm having difficulty in trying to re-deploy a stored procedure in `DB2 10.1 LUW`.

```
CREATE TYPE "TBSGL"."ACCT" AS ROW(
ACCT_NO VARCHAR(10), 
ACCT_DESC VARCHAR(40))

CREATE TYPE "TBSGL"."ACCT_ARR" AS "TBSGL"."ACCT" ARRAY [2147483647]

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TBSGL.TEST_ARRAY_DB2STYLE (IN P_ARRAY TBSGL.ACCT_ARR)
P1:BEGIN
FOR r AS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(P_ARRAY) AS t(ACCT_NO, ACCT_DESC)) DO
    INSERT INTO TBSGL.CHART_ACCT VALUES (r.ACCT_NO,r.ACCT_DESC);
    --CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Account Number '||r.ACCT_NO);
END FOR;
END P1 @
```

This same procedure was working when I first deployed it, after succeeding revisions, I no longer can deploy I've been getting

> "No authorized routine named "UNNEST" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found"

The same set of procedures can be deployed in `DB2 10.5 LUW` consistently. Ive searched thru db2 documentation regarding the unnest table function, and this has been available in versions prior to `10.1`. I've been racking my brains in trying to figure out whats wrong in my procedure.

by the way, as workaround I tried looping through the array manually

```
WHILE i <= CARDINALITY(P_ARRAY) DO
        SET V_FIELD = P_ARRAY[i];
                INSERT INTO TBSGL.CHART_ACCT (ACCT_NO, ACCT_DESC)
                VALUES (V_FIELD.ACCT_NO, V_FIELD.ACCT_DESC);
    --CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Account Number '||v_acct.ACCT_NO);
        SET i = i+1;
    END WHILE;
END P1
```

Im getting

> No authorized routine named "CARDINALITY" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.17.30

Comment: May be you somehow botched the routine search path. Try calling explicitly qualifying the functions, e.g. `SYSIBM.UNNEST(...)`. Check the system catalog: `select * from syscat.routines where routinename = 'UNNEST'`

Comment: Hi. I tried the query in syscat.routines, the table function unnest is not there. I tried both in db2 10.1 and 10.5. Is it possible that im missing a grant in my id? The db wherein the unnest fails im just a user, while the other db 10.5 im the owner.

Comment: You don't need any special priviliges to query catalog views. If you cannot see it, it's not there. The only explanation I can offer is that you got the DB2 version/platform wrong (or the database is somehow damaged, which is less likely).

Comment: Thanks. The weird thing is i was able to deploy similar stored procedures before which used unnest. But now,all of a sudden i can no longer see these functions (cardinality, unnest etc). I guess i can try to ask my dba to create a new database for me just to rule out some scenarios

Comment: It seems the database is indeed damaged, our dba created a new database on the same instance and everything is now working as it should.

Comment: One reason for this behaviour might have been that the database was originally created in an earlier version of DB2 and was not (properly) upgraded to the later version.